# find list of strings in list of strings, return boolean

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to work with lists of strings in python and somehow I can't find a good solution. I want to find a list of strings within a list of strings and return boolean values:

```
import re
sentences = ['Hello, how are you?',
             'I am fine, how are you?',
             'I am fine too, thanks']
bits = ['hello', 'thanks']

re.findall(sentences, bits)

# desired output: [True, False, True]
```

So I want to get an array of booleans with True, if the sentences string contains one or more of the bits. I also tried

```
bits = r'hello|thanks'
```

but I always get the error 'unhashable type: 'list''. I tried converting the lists to arrays, but then the error just says 'unhashable type: 'list''. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Your samples are all just plain alphabetic text, with no actual regular expressions, so you can just use `if word in sentence:`.

Comment: For a regex solution for a generic scenario involving a check for whole words that match start/end/contain special chars, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/ZZxrfA).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a nested list comprehension:

```
sentences = ['Hello, how are you?',
             'I am fine, how are you?',
             'I am fine too, thanks']
bits = ['hello', 'thanks']

[any(b in s.lower() for b in bits) for s in sentences]
# returns:
[True, False, True]
```

If you want to use a regular expression, you need to join `bits` with a pipe character, but you will still need to check each sentence in `sentences` individually.

```
[bool(re.search('|'.join(bits), s, re.IGNORECASE)) for s in sentences]
# returns:
[True, False, True]
```